# Rails: find_by making additional sql query, previously did includes

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got three classes:

```
class Batch
  has_many :final_grade_batches
end

class FinalGradeBatch
  belongs_to :batch
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student
  has_many :final_grade_batches
end
```

I want to retrieve a `final_grade_batch` the following way:

```
batch = Batch.includes(:final_grade_batches).find(1)
batch.final_grade_batches.find_by(student_id: 2)
```

The final lines produces this SQL query:

```
FinalGradeBatch Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "final_grade_batches".* FROM "final_grade_batches" WHERE "final_grade_batches"."batch_id" = $1 AND "final_grade_batches"."student_id" = 2 LIMIT 1  [["batch_id", 1]]
```

If I included `final_grade_batches` in the `Batch` `find` query, why is it looking for the `final grade batch` again? I know it needs to find the one that has the student's id, but should Rails make a query to get that? Isn't it loaded into memory by now?

Is there any way I can get a `final grade batch` without Rails hitting the database again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by` always makes database queries. Substitute it with:

```
batch.final_grade_batches.select( |grade_batch| grade_batch.student_id == 2).first
```

This works with the array you already loaded from the database instead of doing an additional query.